# typeable JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jcombobox

I am sure this has been asked but I can't find it (maybe I don't know how to search for it).

I have a `JComboBox` with lots of values, so navigating through all of them is painful. I would like it to change its selection the way browsers do: when you type the first letter, say `s`, it would select the first element starting with `s`, then if you quickly type the second letter, say `a`, the selection would change to the first element starting with `sa`, and so on.

Just a transparent, "typeable" `JComboBox`, not a `JTextField` where you start typing then a pull-down of options shows up.

Comment: are you looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777473/java-combobox-autocomplete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- have look at [AutoComplete JComboBox / JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7255918/714968)
- another choice is decorator by `SwingX`