# Almost I have a autocompleter JComboBox , almost it's done but I have a wrong

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jcombobox

I know that probably this question was repeat in this forum, but before I choose ask this question I was searching in internet by myself and almost my solution is done, but I have a wall in my face and I can't continue. Probably many people have the same problem when them want to program one autocompleter and this can be a solution for all.

My problem is . when I have the coincidences list , I don't know how I can update the DefaultComboBoxModel , because I'm trap in a infinity loop, because I'm using a documentListener.

Here is the code:

Main code:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{

public MainFrame(){
    initFrame();
}

private void initFrame() {

    setTitle("Auto Completer");
    setSize(284 , 70 );;
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);;
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    GComboBox comboBox = new GComboBox();
    comboBox.getData().add("George");
    comboBox.getData().add("Michael");
    comboBox.getData().add("Mike");
    comboBox.getData().add("Tom");
    comboBox.getData().add("Elvis");
    comboBox.commitData();

    getContentPane().add(comboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
}
```

}

And this is the autocomplete JComboBox

```
public class GComboBox extends JComboBox<String> {

private List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
private DefaultComboBoxModel<String> comboModel;
private JTextComponent editTextField;
private boolean loadFinished = false;

public GComboBox(){
    setEditable(true);
    initComponent();
}

public void commitData(){

    Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < data.size() ; i++){
        vector.add(data.get(i));
    }
    comboModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(vector);
    this.setModel(comboModel);
    editTextField.setText("");
    loadFinished = true;
}

private void initComponent() {
    createDocumentListeners();
}

private void createDocumentListeners() {

    editTextField = (JTextComponent)getEditor().getEditorComponent();
    editTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            update();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            update();
        }

        public void update(){

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    List<String> founds = getCoincidences(editTextField.getText());

                    //if all words was loaded in the combo 
                    if ( loadFinished ){
                        setCoincidencesInModel(founds);
                        setPopupVisible(true);
                        System.out.println("Load finished");
                    }

                    //Here I can see the coincidences
                    for ( String itemFound : founds){
                        System.out.println("Words with coincidences -> " + itemFound);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}


public List<String> getCoincidences(String wordEntered){
    List <String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < data.size() ; i++){
        if( data.get(i).contains(wordEntered)){
            newList.add(data.get(i));
        }
    }
    return newList;
}

public void setCoincidencesInModel(List<String> coincidenceList){
    comboModel.removeAllElements();
    Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>();
    for ( String coincidence : coincidenceList ){
        comboModel.addElement(coincidence);
        vector.add(coincidence);
    }
    DefaultComboBoxModel<String> newModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(vector);
    setModel(newModel);
}

public List<String> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<String> data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

}

Comment: `I don't know how I can update the DefaultComboBoxModel , because I'm trap in a infinity loop, because I'm using a documentListener.` == MutableComboBoxModel, use standard [Autocomplete JComboBox/JTextField](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12042079/714968)